# Yii2: GridView's column is too wide

Tags: gridview, yii2, scrollbar, adminlte, gii

I have `index.php` made by the **Gii** tool that created a CRUD. Also I use **AdminLTE** template.

It has the **GridView** that should show two columns: "Phrase" and "Author" but the column "Phrase" has some rows with long text (around 350 characters) so just **a part of this column is shown**. And the "Author" column is not shown at all.

There is no **horizontal scroll bar** (it should help me):

[image]

Or maybe the problem is the **string** data type:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['phrase'], 'required'],
        [['phrase'], 'string'],
        [['author'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
    ];
}
```

This is my `index.php` view:

```
<div class="box box-primary">
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>                
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'phrase',
            'author',
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the `table-responsive` class to `<div class="box box-primary">`

```
<div class="box box-primary table-responsive">
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'frase',
            'autor',
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{update} {delete}'
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `contentOptions` :

```
[
   'attribute' => 'phrase',
   'contentOptions' => [
       'style' => [
           'max-width' => '600px',
           'white-space' => 'normal',
       ],
   ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
[
    'attribute'=>'phrase',
    'value'=>function($data){
        return strlen($data->phrase) > 100 ? Html::encode(substr($data->phrase, 0, 100)) . ". . ." : $data->phrase;
    }
]
```

It will display the first 100 characters from  the string, if the string size is greater than 100.

Set The Value according to your desired width.

Comment: OP don't want to cut off strings.

Comment: use wordwrap function of php  wordwrap($data->phrase, 8, "\n", true);

Comment: Again, OP don't want to cut off string.